# Difference between running Javascript in Chrome Console and JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, jsfiddle

I'm a newbie to programming (really excited!). I'm testing a function but I don't understand why a simple one function (like the one below) returns the correct result in Chrome Console ( = 12), but not in JSFiddle.

```
var multiply = new Function('x', 'y', 'return x * y');
console.log(multiply(3,4));
```

For learning purposes, do you suggest to practice working only with the Chrome Console and avoiding tools like JSFiddle?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in either FF or Chrome. They both work as expected in console/JSFiddle.

Comment: Can you please share the non-working fiddle?

Comment: In general, you'd use a fiddle if you want to have html and css with your js, or want to try out some features of the more advanced prototyping tools (modules, transpiling etc), all of which are not available in the browser devtools. For plain JS snippets, running them in the devtools console is much simpler.

Comment: `new Function` is not the normal way to define functions. If you're new, I suggest you learn the basics first, before exploring arcane things like this.

Comment: Thank you for the replies insofar! This is the JSfiddle; nothing appears in the white space: https://jsfiddle.net/o841ynvu/ @Bergi, Andy

Comment: @user3926863 Well the white space is the empty html page. The message appears  in the devtools console like any other `console.log` call.

Comment: thank you! my bad, I had not realized that yet :)